# Installing Ubuntu on Mac Mini 5,1

Tags: server, system-installation, mac-mini

I have a mid-2011 Mac Mini 5,1 that I've been trying to install Ubuntu on so I can host Plex.  I don't need Ubuntu, but I have this machine and want to replace macOS with Ubuntu for my media.

I've followed tons of guides, e.g. [this one](http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/) and run into myriad issues based on whether I'm using a server install or a desktop install.  I'd prefer a server/CLI-only setup.

I've tried 16.x and 14.x (server and desktop), but both error out at the 'can't read the cd-rom' step.  There are lots of workarounds recommended for both, but nothing recent and nothing has worked. I've tried both the `dd` method and the UNetbootin app.  I'm using a 128gb SD card.  I press Alt/Option key at boot, see the EFI boot option, get through the keyboard setup, but can't get beyond that screen because it can't read the install media any further.

I want to end up with a single install of Ubuntu, preferably 16.10, not keep any of the current macOS settings, and manage this server remotely.

I've tried quite a bit and can provide all of the diagnostics, but I'm not sure where to start.  Does anyone have a similar setup and run into similar problems?  What other detail can I provide?

Comment: Do you have another PC you could use to confirm the installation media works?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this sorted out.

I was able to EFI boot the Mac Mini via the SD card but it kept failing on the installation from cdrom.  I created another install media onto a USB stick and mounted that to /cdrom.

Once the installer 'saw' the install media it was able to continue.  Ive now got a Ubuntu-only Mac Mini that boots perfectly.